# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION on Windows 8.1 only when I Restart the PC

Tags: windows-8, crash, bsod, dpc

I am getting the dreaded DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION on a newly setup Windows 8.1 rig. It uses a Gigabyte H87-HD3 Motherboard, i5 4570, 16GB RAM and has a Kingston 240GB SSD (no other h/w on the M/b). Logitech Wireless Keyboard K520 + mouse using unified USB receiver. The SSD is setup as SATA, AHCI is ON. UEFI is set to 'UEFI and Legacy'. I did not use the Intel drivers while setting up the SSD, I let Windows partition/format the Drive.

The System is stable otherwise but on almost all 'Restart' it freezes just after the Startup Screen comes up. Most of the times it crashes before password entry, occasionally it gets to password entry but freezes and crashes with DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION soon after. If I power off and start, no issues.

Often I have seen that the network connection showing a yellow exclamation before crashing. I have tried updating the network drivers but no avail. (I am using on-board LAN no WIFI adapter in the system).

I have uploaded the Minidump files [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9FF6A7FB81F93F33!29156&authkey=!AAsALxzkSuELOPY&ithint=file,.zip). Any help with the crash analysis is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was finally resolved by updating the BIOS and drivers via Gigabyte's App Center tool. I first updated the drivers, next, updated the BIOS (from version F5 to F6), rebooted and the BSOD stopped. Haven't got one in last 3 weeks, so I say we are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an audio driver issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!KiUpdateRunTime
03 nt!KiUpdateTime
04 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
05 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
06 nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
07 nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
08 nt!KiInterruptDispatchLBControl
09 HDAudBus!HdaController::Isr
0a nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
0b nt!KiScanInterruptObjectList
0c nt!KiChainedDispatch
0d HDAudBus! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
0e nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs
0f nt!KiRetireDpcList
10 nt!KxRetireDpcList
11 nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue



STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
HDAudBus!HdaController::Isr+13e
fffff800`026fe1cd 488b4628        mov     rax,qword ptr [rsi+28h]

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_HDAudBus!HdaController::Isr

BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_HDAudBus!HdaController::Isr

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_isr_hdaudbus!hdacontroller::isr
```

So Update the realtek audio driver:

```
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RTKVHD64.sys
Image name: RTKVHD64.sys
Timestamp:        Tue Oct 29 11:18:58 2013
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for your inputs. That seems to be latest Driver version from Realtek around. I reverted to MS drivers but that didn't solve anything. Infact it made it worse (required 5+ attempts to bootup, unfortunately WinDbg is refusing to even load the MiniDump files generated). If the Audio device is busted, I guess I can RMA the M/b. One question though, if I disable the Audio device from BIOS and things start working, that should pretty much be all the proof required that Audio device is busted right?

Comment: Looks like disabling Audio from BIOS didn't help. Neither did disabling onboard LAN. I have got a bunch of new MiniDump files http://1drv.ms/1jm1S2r , that seem to all point at different drivers as per BlueScreenViewer.exe. Any new insights will help (feeling sheepish that I can't find the correct Symbol files to do this myself ;-)... )

Comment: OKay, I finally figured out how to use WinDbg to get the Bug Check Analysis and for all the MiniDmp files I can load I get the above analysis. But as the analysis shows above, WinDbg is pointing to HDAudBus. Curious to know how did you relate it to RTKVHD.sys (I am a WinDbg noob so please be kind :-)... )

Comment: Finally some light at the end of the tunnel. Looks like turning Hyper V off solves the WATCHDOG_VIOLATION issue. It is very very similar to this issue http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/32377-dpc_watchdog_violation-windows-8-1-upon-logging.html (which I guess is answered by magicandre there also ;)... ). This gives a little relief that the H/W maynot be faulty, but it's absolutely no-no for me because a major point of the new machine was to use Hyper-V (WP8 development basically)

Comment: this is not me. Contact the Microsoft support about the issue.